# what rar password recovery tools are available?

Tags: password, password-recovery, rar

Long ago I made an archive of images and protected it with a password but I have forgotten the password and I made many trails to crack it with my general combinations but failed.

Are there any reliable solutions?

Comment: opinion-based question

Answer (score 8):

You can try RarCrack.

RarCrack is a command line tool that allows users to recover passwords of compressed archive files.

RarCrack uses the bruteforce algorithm to guess forgotten passwords of archive files. To install RarCrack on Ubuntu 12.04, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ole.wolf/rarcrack
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rarcrack
```

To install on other Ubuntu distributions, you can download from [here](http://rarcrack.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I am using ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Have you tried to download, and install from the link above?

Comment: no luck http://pastebin.com/806fPn3R

Comment: can you help me please.

Comment: I'll try my best, just give me some time:)

Comment: I tried the this method. Worked for me. Here is the output -> http://paste.ubuntu.com/6611095/

Comment: `wget -O rarcrack_0.2-3_amd64.deb https://launchpad.net/~ole.wolf/+archive/rarcrack/+files/rarcrack_0.2-3_amd64.deb  && sudo dpkg -i rarcrack_0.2-3_amd64.deb
`

Answer (score 1):

rarcrack depends on the p7zip package.

Don't forget to install it with `sudo apt-get install p7zip` before (or after you've got the dependency error).